# singleClickEdit is not working in ag-grid-angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have set the singleClickEdit property true to allow single click to start editing cell instead of double click. still i am not able to edit on single click only on double click it is working.
Can you please suggest what could be the solution?

```
   <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
             (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
             class="ag-theme-fresh ag-theme-promotion-grid common-grid-css ag-grid-padding"
             [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
             (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
             [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
             [rowData]="rowData"
             [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
             [suppressMovableColumns]="true"
             [suppressContextMenu]="true"
             [singleClickEdit]="true"
             [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplateFinaliseGrid"
             [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
             [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules"
             [suppressScrollOnNewData]="true"
             [stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus]="true"
             [suppressColumnVirtualisation]="true">
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: if don't provide the value via a variable of your component class, you don't need the square brackets. Try it with: `singleClickEdit="true"`

Comment: @ChrisY still not working :(

Comment: okay sorry, just saw that the example on their site also uses brackets. I will delete my answer for now, since it is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the properties you use to a minimal set. Just to exclude some error possibilities.

Comment: yes tried adding properties one by one still not working :(

Comment: can you try if its working for you in the official example? https://next.plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&preview

Comment: it is working there in official example

Comment: then try to break it :D

Comment: @ChrisY using cellEditor: numericCellEditor is suppressing the feature of singleClickEdit by commenting this property it will work , but i need this property to restrict the user to enter only numeric

Comment: maybe this example helps: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/nPvDekIdsQXmF9Fn 
setting singleClickEdit works for me there

Comment: @ChrisY ok the problem was using frameworkComponents along with singleClickEdit was not working

Comment: @ChrisY Thanks a lot for the plunker code got the solution it was my code was missing below lines    // dont use afterGuiAttached for post gui events - hook into ngAfterViewInit instead for this
   ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.input.element.nativeElement.focus();
    });
}